# How do I implement a database connection/select/close using RxJS observables

Tags: node.js, typescript, rxjs, observable, reactivex

I'm using node-oracledb to connect to an Oracle database. The API provides its own promises, that can be casted to `Promise<T>` and therefore "converted" to `Observable<T>`.

Using Observables, I would like to:

1. Open the database connection
2. Select N records
3. Close the database connection, *even if #2 threw an exception*.

Using the traditional, blocking, procedural way, it would be something like this:

```
try
{
    connection = Oracle.getConnection(...);
    resultSet = connection.execute("SELECT ... FROM ...");
}
catch (Exception)
{
    resultSet = EMPTY_RESULT;
}
finally
{
    if (connection)
        connection.close();
}
```

My attempts at writing this using Observables lead to a lot of code and callbacks.

The protected method getConnection() is still pretty simple:

```
import * as Oracle from "oracledb";

protected getConnection() : Observable<IConnection>
{
    return OraUtil.from(Oracle.getConnection(this.parameters));
}
```

And so is the `closeConnection()` method. I used the promise directly here, to avoid even more code.

```
protected closeConnection(subscriber : Subscriber<IExecuteReturn>, connection : IConnection) : void
{
    connection.close()
        .then(() => subscriber.complete())
        .catch((error) => subscriber.error());
}
```

But the `execute()` method is where the trouble starts.

```
protected _execute(connection : IConnection, statement : string) : Observable<IExecuteReturn>
{
    return new Observable<IExecuteReturn>(
        (subscriber) => {
            OraUtil.from(connection.execute(statement)).subscribe(
                (result) => subscriber.next(result),
                (error) => {
                    subscriber.error(error);
                    this.closeConnection(subscriber, connection);
                },
                () => {
                    this.closeConnection(subscriber, connection);
                });
        });
}

public execute(statement : string) : Observable<IExecuteReturn>
{
    return this.getConnection().pipe(
        flatMap((connection) => this._execute(connection, statement))
    );
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is how I generally handle connection management. The core is `using` observable creator that accepts resource factory as first argument and setup function as second.

```
using(() => { unsubscribe() }, resource => observableOf(resource))
```

The `resource` is an object with `unsubscribe` method that gets called as part of unsubscription - so you can hide any logic there and effectively bind lifecycle of arbitrary object to lifecycle of an observable.

I hope the code below makes sense.

```js
import * as Oracle from "oracledb";
import { mergeMap , ignoreElements} from 'rxjs/operators';
import { using } from 'rxjs/observable/using';
import { from as observableFrom } from 'rxjs/observable/from';
import { concat } from 'rxjs/observable/concat';
import { defer } from 'rxjs/observable/defer';
import { empty as observableEmpty } from 'rxjs/observable/empty';

class OracleConnection {
  constructor(parameters) {
    this.isClosed = false;
    this.connection = null;
    this.parameters = parameters;
  }

  setup() {
    return defer(() => Oracle.getConnection(this.parameters)
      .then(connection => { // do this in promise in case observable gets unsubscribed before connection is established
        this.connection = connection;
        if (this.isClosed) { // close in case connection got already closed before even got established
          this.terminate();
        }
        return connection;
      }));
  }

  close() {
    this.isClosed = true;
    if (this.connection !== null) {
      const connection = this.connection;
      this.connection = null;

      return observableFrom(connection.close())
        .pipe(ignoreElements()) // only propagate errors
    }

    return observableEmpty(); // connection already closed
  }
  
  terminate() {
    this.close().subscribe(/* handle error from connection close */);
  }

  unsubscribe() { // this will get called on observable unsubscribe
    if (!this.isClosed) {
      this.terminate();
    }
  }
}

class ConnectionManager {
  constructor(params) {
    this.params = params;
  }

  getConnection() {
    return using(() => new OracleConnection(this.params), oracleConnection => oracleConnection.setup())
  }
}

const manager = new ConnectionManager({ /* some params */ });

manager.getConnection()
  .pipe(
    mergeMap(connection => concat(
      connection.execute('SELECT 1'),
      connection.close() // explicitly close connection
    )),
    // alternatively
    // take(1) // to close connection automatically
  );
```

Cool thing you can do for example is easily retry the connection in case of failure:

```js
oracle.getConnection()
  .pipe(
    retry(3)
    ...
  );
```

Comment: It took me a whole while to test this, but this is it.
The keywords here are `using` and `concat`.

`using` allows me to return some kind of "managed" connection which automatically closes when unsubscribing.
`concat` allows me to create a chain of various observables, and to return only the values that match its output type.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, when using RxJs 6.x, something like "connect + execute + close" sequence is implemented along these lines

```
let connection;

Oracle.getConnection(....)
.pipe(
  switchMap(conn => {
    connection = conn;
    return connection.execute(statement);
  }),
  finalize(() => connection.close())
)
.subscribe(
  result => resultSet = result,
  error => {
    console.error(error);
  }
)
```

Syntactic details may be different, but the key idea is that once the connection Observable emits, then you `switchMap` to execute the statement. The whole chain is activated when you subscribe. In the subscription you close the connection in case of error or when the Observable returned by the execution completes.

Comment: Although this is a relatively light implementation, the fact that I have to "care" about closing the connection in various cases in the subscribe callback makes this solution a bit less attractive.

Comment: You can centralize the `close` operation into the `finalize` operator. I have updated my answer.